# Division in process

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing, tikz-graphs

This is the process of Euclidean Algorithm to find $\gcd(a,b)$. Could anyone help me hơ to draw the process of division? Thank all[image: Euclidean Algorithm]

Comment: Hi Minh, welcome to TeX.SX! This is your fifth question, and all are of the form: "Here is a picture, who can do it for me?" So far, it worked well, but in case you don't get an answer, consider to try it first yourself and then ask specific questions when you get stuck, showing your code that you have at this point. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14159]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{every node/.style={minimum width=25pt, minimum height=15pt}}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
        
        \node (R1) at (0,0) {288};
        \foreach \d/\q/\r [count = \i] in
            {804/2/228,
            288/1/60,
            228/3/48,
            60/1/12,
            48/4/0}
            %
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i+1}         
            \node[below= of R\i] (Q\i) {\q};
            \node[left =of R\i] (D\i) {\d};     
            \node[below= of D\i] (R\j) {\r};
            \draw [shorten >=4pt]   (R\i.south west) -- (R\i.south east);
            \draw(R\i.north west) -- (Q\i.south west);
            }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: O-clit]

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked in my .tex file.

Comment: I edited to change the shortening to 4pt, since it seemed better to my eyes.

Comment: Could be interesting to mix this solution with the script in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583321/euclidean-algorithm-command