# Euclidean Algorithm Command

Tags: macros, spacing, formatting, algorithms, alignment

I am currently trying to improve my LaTeX skills, so I have found a list of exercises by Jason Gross [here](http://web.mit.edu/jgross/www/LaTeX/Really%20Hard%20Exercises%20Become%20a%20LaTeXer.pdf).

The exercises that I am trying to complete is 1.5 Euclidean Algorithm.

I have managed to create a newcommand that can print out all of the steps just like it is asked to, but now i can't figure out how to keep the alignement. As you can see on the website, all of the '=' are perfectly aligned from one line to the next, but i can't figure out how to do that.

Here is the command that i wrote, (i tried to cheese the displaying but i could not align the equal symbols...)

```
\newif\ifgeq \newcount\a \newcount\b \newcount\r \newcount\q \newcount\step
\newcommand{\euclidean}[3][1]{\step=#1 \a=#2 \b=#3 \[\]\vspace{-1cm}
    \loop\ifnum\b>0 \q=0 \r=\a \find \printIntDiv \a=\b \b=\r \repeat \begin{center}The gcd of #2 and #3 is equal to \number\a\end{center}}
\def\isgeq{\ifnum\r<\b \global\geqfalse\fi}
\def\find{{\global\geqtrue \isgeq
    \loop\ifgeq \global\advance\q by1 \global\advance\r by-\b \isgeq \repeat}}
\def\printIntDiv{\ifnum\step=1 \[ \number\a = \number\q \cdot \number\b + \number\r \] \vspace{-0.6cm}\fi}

\euclidean{377}{610}
```

The main problem seems to be coming from the fact that i am typesetting the steps as i get them, and that is making the alignement hard. However i do not know how i can proceed without typesetting them as i get them because i don't know out to 'store' them other wise.

If anyone can help me out it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To start with, you should restructure the code such that the steps are not typeset as independent displayed math. Otherwise alignment is difficult, as you would have to counter everything that display math does. You can generate the lines of an `array` by your macros.

Comment: @gernot, Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I am quite new to all these LaTeX commandes and macros, so I understand what you are saying, by I am not sure how to display the steps without typesetting them progressively. I am pretty sure that I can't store the different step in lists or anything so i really don't know how to.     I tried to type set everything in an array environment, i got closer to the alignement but it still wasn't perfect (and i had to \hphantom so it was really not the best solution). If you can, could you help me out?

Comment: You don't have to do everything at once. Something like: If display then begin-code endif; compute_gcd, if display then end-code endif; print result. And compute_gcd tests also the display variable and outputs lines like  999 &= 99*9+9.

Comment: BTW, I don't think that this list of exercises is an adequate starting point for learning LaTeX. Rather, if someone considers him/herself as proficient in (La)TeX and has lots of time, then these exercises are maybe a reasonable replacement for doing Sudokus.

Comment: You might be interested in Michael Downes [Around the Bend](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf) TeX Challenges. You might be interested in the [collection of TeX pearls of the Polish TeX User Group](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/). If you can cope with German language: David Kastrup: [De Ore Leonis - Makroexpansion für Virtuosen](https://www.yumpu.com/de/document/read/36550731/david-kastrup-de-ore-leonis-makroexpansion-fa-1-4-r-virtuosen).

Comment: I think, in order to improve (La)TeX skills the most important thing is grasping the underlying concepts and stages of TeX's "digestion" of .tex-input and the order in time in which things take place during the (La)TeX-run: Category codes and tokenization. Expansion/expansion-based algorithms, e.g., `\romannumeral`-expansion-based algorithms. Assignments. Boxes. Math-Mode. Output-routines.  Then turn towards LaTeX 2e: What is the purpose of the different auxiliary-files. When are they read and when are they created/written? Have a look at the ...

Comment: ... Have a look at the [commented sources of the LaTeX 2e-kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) and try to figure out how cross-referencing (`\label` and `\ref`) is implemented. Then try to figure out how the packages hyperref and zref enhance this. Then look at the package [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and at the [LaTeX 3/expl3 interfaces](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). I wrote all this assuming "improving your skills" means improving skills in implementing things, not just "black-box"-using things provided by others.

Comment: @UlrichDiez thank you so much for the tips, i appreciate it so much. And just to clarify, i was trying to improve my LaTeX skills for defining macros and commands, just to see how they work... That is why i found these exercises online, and tried to do them.  I really appreciate your help  and will check out the exercises and explanations.

Comment: IMO you could use Lua in LuaTeX instead. There's no need for self-punishment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an alignment, accumulating material as you go on and delivering it at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifgeq
\newcount\a
\newcount\b
\newcount\r
\newcount\q
\newcount\step

\newcommand{\euclidean}[3][1]{%
  \[\begin{gathered}
  \step=#1 \a=#2 \b=#3
  \gdef\sofar{}%
  \gdef\result{\number\b}%
  \loop\ifnum\b>0
    \q=0
    \r=\a
    \find
    \printIntDiv
    \a=\b
    \b=\r
  \repeat
  \begin{aligned}\sofar\end{aligned} \\[0.5ex]
  \text{The gcd of $#2$ and $#3$ is equal to $\result$}
  \end{gathered}\]
}
\def\isgeq{\ifnum\r<\b \global\geqfalse\fi}
\def\find{{% <-- group
  \global\geqtrue
  \isgeq
  \loop\ifgeq
    \global\advance\q by1
    \global\advance\r by-\b
    \isgeq
  \repeat
}}
\def\printIntDiv{%
  \ifnum\step=1
    \xdef\sofar{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\sofar}%
      \number\a &= \number\q \cdot \number\b + \number\r\noexpand\\
    }%
  \xdef\result{\number\b}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\euclidean{377}{610}

\euclidean{24}{18}

\euclidean{4}{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A “simpler” implementation with `expl3`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_needle_euclid_steps_tl
\tl_new:N \l_needle_euclid_gcd_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \needle_euclid_steps:nn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_needle_euclid_steps_tl
   {
    #1 &= \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } \cdot #2 + \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } \exp_not:N \\
   }
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } > 0 }
   {
    \needle_euclid_steps:ne { #2 } { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_needle_euclid_gcd_tl { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \needle_euclid_steps:nn { ne }

\NewDocumentCommand{\euclidean}{mm}
 {
  \[
    \needle_euclid_steps:nn { #1 } { #2 }
    \begin{gathered}
      \begin{aligned}
      \l_needle_euclid_steps_tl
      \end{aligned} \\[0.5ex]
      \text{The~gcd~of~$#1$~and~$#2$~is~$\l_needle_euclid_gcd_tl$}
    \end{gathered}\]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\euclidean{377}{610}

\euclidean{24}{18}

\euclidean{4}{2}

\end{document}
```

The main function `\needle_euclid_steps:nn` does the job of computing quotient and remainder; it appends the step and recursively calls itself unless the last remainder is zero. At this point it records the last remainder and quits the recursion.

Just computing the gcd is much simpler, but the idea is the same

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\computegcd}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 = 0 }
   { #1 } % #2 = 0, do nothing and return #1
   { \needle_gcd:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \needle_gcd:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } = 0 }
   { #2 }
   { \needle_gcd:ne { #2 } { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \needle_gcd:nn { ne }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: @egref I just wanted to make sure that when you call `\xdef\sofar{\unexpanded\expandafter{\sofar}...`, you use `\unexpanded\expandafter` because `\xdef` will expand `\unexpanded` so it cancels out? Could you confirm this?   Also, why do you `\noexpand \\ ` ?

Comment: @egred EDIT: i found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140785/how-is-unexpanded-defined) an explanation, so if i understood correctly, at the beginning, you define for `\gdef\sofar`, than after each iteration of the `\loop`, you call `\printIntDiv` and you 'update' `\sofar` with `\number\a = ...`. Using `\xdef` makes `\global\edef` so you expand `\sofar`, which than expands `\unexpanded\expandafter{\sofar}`. What i don't understand if `\expandafter{\sofar}` expands `\sofar` before `{`, or if it expands `\number\a = ...` before `\sofar`

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of having fun and to get introduced to the matter a short tail-recursive routine which does with `\numexpr` from the ε-TeX-extensions for the subtraction.

(One could replace `\number\numexpr...\relax` by an own `\romannumeral`-expansion-driven expandable subtraction-routine. But why? Nowadays LaTeX doesn't work without ε-TeX-extensions.)

It is suitable only for calculating gcds of **natural** numbers.

It does not print the single steps. It just delivers the result.

There is no checking implemented if arguments form **natural** numbers/if the requirements for the arguments are fulfilled.

Instead of using temporary macros as variables and doing temporary assignments all the time for storing values of variables, macro arguments are used as "variables". In the tail-recursive loop the values of "variables" are changed by changing the corresponding macro-arguments for the next iteration.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Pseudocode:
%% 
%% Euclid(#1,#2)  //  Calculates gcd(#1,#2). 
%%                //  #1 and #2 are to be _natural_ numbers !!
%% 
%%     WHILE #2 =/= 0
%%       IF #1 > #2 THEN
%%         #1 :=  #1 - #2
%%       ELSE
%%         #2 :=  #2 - #1
%%       ENDIF
%%     ENDWHILE
%%     RESULT := #1
%%
\newcommand\UDPassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UDfirstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UDsecondoftwo[2]{#2}%

\newcommand\Euclid[2]{%
  \ifnum#2=0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
  {#1}{%
    \ifnum#1>#2 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \expandafter\Euclid\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-#2\relax}{#2}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\number\numexpr#2-#1\relax}{\Euclid{#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

gcd(377; 610) is: \Euclid{377}{610}

\noindent\hrulefill

gcd(144; 960) is: \Euclid{144}{960}

\noindent\hrulefill

gcd(960; 144) is:  \Euclid{960}{144}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

For the sake of having more fun an expandable tail-recursive routine which does with `\numexpr` from the ε-TeX-extensions for the subtraction.

It is suitable for calculating gcds of **integers**.

It does print the single steps.

There is no checking implemented if arguments form **integers**/if the requirements for the arguments are fulfilled.

Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is delivered after "hitting" with `\expandafter` twice.

You might consider doing arithmetic and comparison of numbers by means of the expandable routines of the package [bigintcalc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc).

By the way:

The routine "says" that gcd(0,0) is undefined.
It "says" so because it is an implementation of Euclid's algorithm while Euclid left gcd(0,0) undefined.

If "greatest" in "greatest common divisor" does refer to the partial order of divisibility on the natural numbers, then gcd(0,0)=0.

Besides this, if "greatest" in "greatest common divisor" does refer to the partial order of divisibility on the natural numbers, then there usually is not just one gcd. E.g., if the natural number `x` is the greatest common divisor referring to the order of integers, then referring to the partial order of divisibility on the natural numbers, gcds are `x` and `-x`.

Changing the routine accordingly should be straightforward and therefore is left as an exercise for the interested. ;->

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\UDPassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UDExchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UDfirstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UDsecondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\UDstopromannumeral{\chardef\UDstopromannumeral=`\^^00}%

\newcommand\Euclidean[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  % Wrapping between braces as argument of \UDExchange might help ensuring that
  % things won't get disturbed if carried out insige a tabular-environment or
  % the like.
  \expandafter\UDExchange\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral
    \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter{\number#2}%
                {\expandafter\EuclideanSignCheck\expandafter{\number#1}}%
  }{\UDstopromannumeral}%
}%

\newcommand\EuclideanSignCheck[2]{%
  \ifnum#1=0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi{%
    \ifnum#2=0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi{%
       \UDstopromannumeral
       \[\begin{gathered}\text{The gcd of #1 and #2 is not defined.}\end{gathered}\]%
    }{%
       \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral
          \expandafter\UDExchange
          \expandafter{\number\ifnum#2<0 -\fi\number#2.}%
                      {\UDstopromannumeral The gcd of #1 and #2 is }%
       }{\UDstopromannumeral\[\begin{gathered}\text}%
       \end{gathered}\]%
    }%
  }{%
    \ifnum#2=0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi{%
       \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
          \romannumeral
          \expandafter\UDExchange
          \expandafter{\number\ifnum#1<0 -\fi\number#1.}%
                      {\UDstopromannumeral The gcd of #1 and #2 is }%
       }{\UDstopromannumeral\[\begin{gathered}\text}%
       \end{gathered}\]%
    }{%
      \ifnum#1<0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
      {%
         \ifnum#2<0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
         {%
           \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter{\number-#2}%
                       {\expandafter\EuclideanLoopStart\expandafter{\number-#1}}%
                       {\UDfirstoftwo}%
         }%
         {\expandafter\EuclideanLoopStart\expandafter{\number-#1}{#2}{\UDfirstoftwo}}%
      }%
      {%
         \ifnum#2<0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
         {%
           \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond
           \expandafter{\number-#2}%
                       {\EuclideanLoopStart{#1}}%
                       {\UDfirstoftwo}%
         }%
         {\EuclideanLoopStart{#1}{#2}{\UDsecondoftwo}}%
      }%
      {The gcd of #1 and #2 is equal to }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\newcommand\EuclideanLoopStart[4]{%
  %#1 = absolute value of 1st number
  %#2 = absolute value of 2nd number
  %#3 = \UDfirstoftwo/\UDsecondoftwo - flag indicating if switching sign occurred
  %#4 = begin of result-phrase, holding initial numbers
  #3{%
    \EuclideanLoop{#1}{0}{#2}{#1}{}{#4}{the gcd of #1 and #2:}%
  }{%
    \EuclideanLoop{#1}{0}{#2}{#1}{}{#4}{}%
  }%
}%

\newcommand\EuclideanLoop[7]{%
  %#1 = minuend
  %#2 = amount of subtractions since last switching subtrahend to minuend
  %#3 = subtrahend
  %#4 = value of minuend at last switching subtrahend to minuend
  %#5 = \\-separated list of steps
  %#6 = begin of result-phrase, holding initial numbers
  %#7 = phrase to insert at the begin
  \ifnum#3=0 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \expandafter\UDExchange\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \ifx\relax#5\relax\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
      {\UDstopromannumeral}{%
        \ifx\relax#7\relax\expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
        {\UDstopromannumeral}{%
          \UDstopromannumeral\text{\textit{[#6#7]}}\\[0.5ex]%
        }%
        \begin{aligned}#5\end{aligned}\\[0.5ex]%
      }%
    }{\UDstopromannumeral\[\begin{gathered}}%
    \text{#6#4.}\end{gathered}\]%
  }{%
    \ifnum#1<#3 \expandafter\UDfirstoftwo\else\expandafter\UDsecondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \EuclideanLoop{#3}{0}{#1}{#3}{#5\mathbf{#4}&=#2\cdot\mathbf{#3}+\mathbf{#1}\\}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UDPassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter{\number\numexpr#2+1\relax}{%
        \expandafter\EuclideanLoop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-#3\relax}%
      }{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    }%
    {#6}{#7}%
  }%
}%



\begin{document}

\Euclidean{377}{610}

\noindent\hrulefill

\Euclidean{144}{960}

\noindent\hrulefill

\Euclidean{960}{144}

\noindent\hrulefill

\Euclidean{-1380451}{24361}

\noindent\hrulefill

\Euclidean{0}{-12}

\noindent\hrulefill

\Euclidean{-12}{0}

\noindent\hrulefill

\Euclidean{0}{0}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim*}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \Euclidean{-1380451}{24361}%
}%
\end{verbatim*}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \Euclidean{-1380451}{24361}%
}%
\begingroup\ttfamily\frenchspacing\string\test: \meaning\test\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: amazing! thank you so much